# Do cyclists make safer drivers?

Tags: safety, traffic

Is there any research that suggests cyclists are safer drivers than drivers who don't cycle? Is there evidence to suggest the opposite?

Please remember this is not a discussion. **Please include references to credible research in your answer.**

Comment: I vote to close. "Are there any studies or statistics that conclude cyclists are safer, better, or more law abiding drivers, than drivers who don't cycle?" Right! Many cyclists here in cycling heaven ride with complete "abandon". By "abandon", I mean no lights at night, no helments, wearing dark clothes at night, etc

Comment: On the other hand, cyclists may be better drivers. When I arrive at an intersection while driving, I do give it some thought. Last week, after stopping at a stop sign on a dark, rainy night, I came *very* close to pulling out into a cyclist with no lights, dark clothing, etc. My "cyclist" mentality made me look twice.

Comment: Just for the sake of argument, I'll say that, on average, and in my estimation, adult cyclists (of the in-traffic variety) in the US are apt to be better drivers than non-cyclists. A little more aware, particularly of pedestrians at intersections, hazardous driveway crossings, etc. But I doubt that there is any hard evidence to this effect, or any easy way to collect it. It's hard enough, eg, coming up with statistics on bike safety.

Comment: Those people who ride around without lights, at night in dark clothing aren't cyclists, they're cyclist shaped objects.  Same goes for the people who spend $2000 on a bike and then proceed to ride it at 15 km/h.  (Don't take me too seriously)

Comment: I've voted to re-open, but I think the question would be better if it defined what a better driver is, and what kind of cyclist we're talking about. (There was an explanation of that in an earlier version of the question.) Another tactic would be to ask if vehicular cycling enhances driving skills, and if so, how?

Comment: @JasonS - I'm guessing there's a story behind why you're asking this. It'd make a great blog post; ping me or Gary.Ray or freiheit in chat if you're interested.

Comment: @ jason s - "I want research" - Totally understand. However, not sure that there is valid research linking "cyclist drivers" vs "non-cyclist drivers" as for safety. Perhaps?

Comment: @ Jason - I actually like your question. I just can't find any research linking cyclists vs non-cyclists to driver safety. I am inclined to think that a cyclist might be a better driver...however, considering some cyclists I've seen, maybe not.

Comment: I am more careful myself around cyclists and so is my wife ,so I think if everyone contributes a little bit it does get bigger.

Comment: Too bad the [NHTSA](http://www-fars.nhtsa.dot.gov/QueryTool/QuerySection/SelectFields.aspx) doesn't ask drivers if they're also cyclists.

Comment: Other potential sources of relevant research: http://www.fhwa.dot.gov/research/library/index.cfm http://www.fhwa.dot.gov/research/publications/technical/ http://www.fhwa.dot.gov/publications/research/safety/humanfac/06034/chapt3.cfm http://safety.fhwa.dot.gov/

Comment: Somewhat relevant:  [Are bicycles and cars in a war for American streets?](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/magazine-15156336)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a report from the Institute of Advanced Motoring on [Cycling Motorists](http://www.iam.org.uk/images/stories/downloads/Cycling/IAMcyclingreportWEB.pdf). The vast majority of motorists believe that cyclists do make safer drivers.

Even those motorists who don't cycle believe that cyclists are safer drivers.

[image]

Comment: More opinions, of course, but at least the opinions (on that one issue) are leaning in our favor.

Comment: @DanielRHicks At least this is based on over 1000 opinions from a cross-section of people and qualifies as credible research. +1 and I'm marking this as an answer until something better comes along. Surprising results though. It would be interesting what similar surveys would produce here in Sydney. The ones done by the tabloid newspapers always come up with negative attitudes towards cyclists.